# Java Queue add()/offer() and poll() method not working according to FIFO as expected

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue, palindrome

I want to try to solve the "PALINDROME" problem using queue and stack i am using the corresponding methods like `push/pop`  and `offer()[or add()]/poll()`  for inserting and removing the element from stack and queue respectively.But it seems enqueing and dequeing   of elements in/from a queue does not work according to FIFO order.

```
  public class Testhis{
      Stack<Character> st=new Stack<Character>();
      PriorityQueue<Character> qu=new PriorityQueue();
      public void pushCharacter(Character c){
       st.push(c);
      }
     public void enqueueCharacter(Character c){
        qu.offer(c);
     }
    public  char popCharacter(){
       return st.pop();
    }
    public  char dequeueCharacter(){

        return qu.poll();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = scan.nextLine();
         scan.close();

        // Convert input String to an array of characters:
        char[] s = input.toCharArray();

        // Create a Solution object:
        Testhis p = new Testhis();

        // Enqueue/Push all chars to their respective data structures:
       for (char c : s) {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("char in action="+c);
           System.out.println();
           p.pushCharacter(c);
           p.enqueueCharacter(c);

        }



   // Pop/Dequeue the chars at the head of both data structures and     
   compare them:

    boolean isPalindrome = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length/2; i++) {
        if (p.popCharacter() != p.dequeueCharacter()) {
            isPalindrome = false;                
            break;
        }
    }
         //Finally, print whether string s is palindrome or not.
         System.out.println( "The word, " + input + ", is " 
                       + ( (!isPalindrome) ? "not a palindrome." : "a   palindrome." ) );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you give some sample input/outputs?

Comment: in:madam

out:The word, madam, is not a palindrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `PriorityQueue`. From the java docs found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html : the order in a  `PriorityQueue` is determined by a given comparator. If none is given, the natural ordering will be used. In your case: let `c1` and `c2` be  characters and let's assume `c1 < c2`, then `c1` will be before `c2` in the queue, no matter in what order they were inserted.  So even if you added `c2` first, you will get `c1` before `c2`. So you'd need to use a different kind of queue or a list.

**Edit:** As @ChiefTwoPencils stated, existing implementations of `Queue` my be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

Comment: what is the alternative ... do we need to implement the queue interface or there is any existing implementation of queue that will help here?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html @rydz

Answer (score 1):

["Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner. Among the exceptions are priority queues..."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). You should probably use the standard `Queue` instead of `PriorityQueue`.